# Remove a specific part of a string

Tags: c#, .net, string, replace

I want to go through a text file and remove specific parts of the string.
In this case I want to remove the path:

```
PERFORMER "Charles Lloyd"

TITLE "Mirror"

FILE "Charles Lloyd\[2010] Mirror\01. I Fall In Love Too Easily.wav" WAVE

TRACK 01 AUDIO

FILE "Charles Lloyd\[2010] Mirror\02. Go Down Moses.wav" WAVE
```

to

```
PERFORMER "Charles Lloyd"

TITLE "Mirror"

FILE "01. I Fall In Love Too Easily.wav" WAVE //here are the changes

TRACK 01 AUDIO

FILE "02. Go Down Moses.wav" WAVE //here are the changes
```

I tried out things like: (given the string s which contains the whole text)

```
s = s.Remove(s.IndexOf("FILE") + 5, (s.IndexOf("\\") + 1) - s.IndexOf("FILE") - 5);
```

and repeat this function to remove the part between "FILE " " and the following backslash

It removes the part correctly, but I would have to manually adjust the number of times it has to run this function (run once for every backslash per line). But this algorithm lacks flexibility and I don't know how to make it approach the next line that starts with "FILE" and begin the procedure again...

Comment: The `IndexOf` method takes a second argument which tells it where to start searching for the matching string.

Comment: If the line is always starting with `File` and ending with `WAVE` you can see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your text is one string variable, you could first split it, and than do replacements for all strings and than join again (assume your text is variable `lines`):

```
var strings = lines.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var replacedStrings = new List<string>();
foreach (var s in strings)
{       
    string replaced;
    if (s.StartsWith("FILE"))
    {
        var sWithoutFile = s.Substring(5);
        replaced = s.Substring(0, 6) +
                    sWithoutFile.Substring(sWithoutFile.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
    }
    else
    {
        replaced = s;
    }
    replacedStrings.Add(replaced);
}   
var result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, replacedStrings);
```

Comment: But there are several lines containing "FILE .... \text\text\song", so how can I find things for every line that contains the word "FILE"

Comment: @Csharpest yes, you are right, sorry, i have changed the solution.

Comment: "replaced" is a string in this context?

Comment: Yes, the result string.

Comment: Ok, this example refers to a single line that either contains FILE or not, right? But what I am dealing with is a single string that contains all these lines. How could I iterate through the whole string, finding the parts that include "FILE"?

Comment: Incredible! This has done the job! I'm very thankful! Although I have a question: I don't understand the arguments you are passing to the "Split" method (line 1). How does the string gets split up to use the foreach loop?

Comment: @Csharpest First parameter is a separator between string parts to be splitted. I use variable, that defines for current environment  the new line symbols: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx  Look hier more about split method: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/73/common-string-operations/9790/splitting-a-string-by-another-string#t=201612191153118698871.

Comment: Ok, so it assumes that the string/text is not written in a single line? If it would be a single line, there would be just one "var s" in "strings" right?

Comment: Yes, you are right, it assumes exact the data structure you described in your question.  If you don't have line breaks as a separator, it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your line always start with `FILE "` and EndsWith `" WAVE`, you can use `System.Io.Path.GetFilename()` Function to achieve this:

```
If str.StartsWith("File"){

string strResult = "FILE """ + IO.Path.GetFileName(str.Substring(6,str.Length - 12)) + """ WAVE";

}
```

**Example:**

```
FILE "Charles Lloyd\[2010] Mirror\01. I Fall In Love Too Easily.wav" WAVE
```

**Result:**

```
FILE "01. I Fall In Love Too Easily.wav" WAVE
```

You can read more about this Function in this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Split the array using character `\` and store the last element in the array back to the string.

For Example something like this:

```
array = file.split('\')

file = array[array.size - 1];
```

Answer (score 1):

What about Regular Expressions.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class RemovePaths
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = @"
PERFORMER ""Charles Lloyd""

TITLE ""Mirror""

FILE ""Charles Lloyd\[2010] Mirror\01. I Fall In Love Too Easily.wav"" WAVE

TRACK 01 AUDIO

FILE ""Charles Lloyd\[2010] Mirror\02. Go Down Moses.wav"" WAVE";

        string test = @"
PERFORMER ""Charles Lloyd""

TITLE ""Mirror""

FILE ""01. I Fall In Love Too Easily.wav"" WAVE

TRACK 01 AUDIO

FILE ""02. Go Down Moses.wav"" WAVE";

        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"(?<=\"").*\\(?=.+\"")");
        string result = rgx.Replace(input, "");
        Console.WriteLine(result == test ? "Pass" : "Fail");
    }
}
```

Breakdown of the RegEx...

(?<=\"")  <--- must start with a double-quote but be excluded using (?<=...)

.*\  <--- match any text up to and including a "\".  note: .* matches anything

(?=.+\"") <--- skip at least one character(.+) and it must end with a double-quote(\").